# Sample size calculation: difference between 'linear multiple regression test' & 'linear bivariate regression' test G*Power 3.1

Tags: statistical-power, gpower

I am trying to calculate a sample size using G*Power 3.1 for a linear model with multiple independent variables, but only two "primary" predictors of interest plus an interaction term between them.

I tried plugging in the relevant information into both "Linear multiple regression: Fixed model, one regression coefficient" and "Linear Bivariate regression: one-group, size of slope" under the t-test family.

I've looked over the [guide](http://www.gpower.hhu.de/fileadmin/redaktion/Fakultaeten/Mathematisch-Naturwissenschaftliche_Fakultaet/Psychologie/AAP/gpower/GPower31-BRM-Paper.pdf) but I cannot figure out what the difference between the test options. I get very different sample sizes from each - the bivariate regression being much bigger. I guess I'm not understanding the difference between them - it seems like the multiple regression option with just 1 predictor should be the same as the bivariate regression, but apparently I'm way off.

Can anyone help clear this up for me?

Comment: I think the first is for testing a model with a single variable, and the second is for testing the effect of a single variable in a model with other variables present.

Comment: So which would you expect to have higher power? If the outcome and main variable of interests is the same between the two?

Comment: It depends how you entered the effect size (and anything else). [I'm not on a windows machine, so I can't play with GPower.]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Effect size is 0.2 and SDs for X and Y are 0.5... for linear bivariate I got sample size of 191 and for multiple with 7 predictors I got ~34.